# Is there any solution to have an image slider with more than one image in a row in xamarin.forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I need to have an image slider with 3 images in a row in xamarin forms.
[image: image slider that I need]

I have tried rotating normal list view, but it has some problems in UI and I really do not like this solution.

Comment: I think use listview is a good solution or you can use scrollView.You can provide your sample so that I can improve it on my side.